# Is it possible to break at implicitly declared method of a templated class in gdb?

Tags: c++, templates, gdb

Here's an example. I've tried setting a break with 3-4 combinations of signatures, but everything was detected as undefined.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class C
{
public:
    void f(){std::cout << "f()\n";}
};

int main()
{
   C<int> c1;
   C<int> c2(c1);
   c2.f();
}

 Both "b C::C(const C&)" and 
      "b C<int>::C(const C<int>&)" fail to break at implicitly declared copy constructor.
```

Comment: gdb only knows symbols defined by the compiler. if the compiler doesn't emit a symbol, gdb has nothing to break at.